# How to make circular Scrollbar progress

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-deployment

https://portfolio-4bc43.web.app/
This is the link to my site. Check the circular scroll progress bar in the bottom right corner. I copied this element from https://filippoinzaghi.com/trophies/ It was working one day and the next day it stopped suddenly. I copied the element html, css and js all from that site. You can easily find the tags in my html and css files within scrollbar percent comments and js is also in the html file. Does anyone knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Seems you forgot to add jQuery to your project